# Check background image is visible on the page using JavsScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Please note that I don't want only to check whether the image loaded in the browser. I want to check whether the image is visible on the page.

**Problem Background:**
I'm using the chrome-php library to take screenshots of HTML using a headless Chrome browser by first loading HTML in Chrome and then taking screenshot. The code was working fine until I started using HD images in the HTML then that screenshot service is still working but sometimes it takes the screenshot however background image of the overlay element is not visible in the screenshot.

The most important piece here to consider is the JS piece that has the logic to check image is loaded + the overlay element is visible but still, I don't have a code to verify image is actually visible. I'm also using a loop to continuously check whether the global js variables went true or not.

```
        $page = $browser->createPage();
        $page->setViewport($width, $height)->await(); // wait for the operation to complete
        $page->setHtml($html, 5000);

        //we are going to check if the image is being loaded
        // Execute JavaScript code to set up the variable isBackgroundImageLoaded and check overlay visibility
        $jsInitialization = <<<JS
        // Set boolean variables to track whether the background image and overlay div are loaded and visible
        let isBackgroundImageLoaded = false;
        let isOverlayVisible = false;

        // Function to check if the background image is loaded
        function checkBackgroundImageLoaded() {
            // Select the overlay div
            const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

            // Create an image element to load the background image
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = getComputedStyle(overlay).backgroundImage.replace(/url\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)/i, "$1");

            // Check if the image has loaded
            img.onload = function() {
                // Set the boolean variable to true when the image has loaded
                isBackgroundImageLoaded = true;

                // Check if the overlay div is visible within the viewport and has non-zero dimensions
                const rect = overlay.getBoundingClientRect();
                const isVisible = (
                    rect.width > 0 &&
                    rect.height > 0 &&
                    rect.top >= 0 &&
                    rect.left >= 0 &&
                    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
                    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                );
                
                // Set the boolean variable to true if both conditions are met
                isOverlayVisible = isVisible;
            };
        }

        // Call the function to check if the background image is loaded and overlay div is visible
        checkBackgroundImageLoaded();
        JS;


        // Execute the JavaScript code in the client's browser
        $page->evaluate($jsInitialization);

        // Polling loop to wait for the background image to be loaded
        $timeout = 9000; // Timeout in milliseconds
        $startTime = microtime(true);

        while (microtime(true) - $startTime < $timeout) {
            // Evaluate the JavaScript variable in the browser
            $evaluation = $page->evaluate("isBackgroundImageLoaded;");
            $isImageLoaded = $evaluation->getReturnValue();

            $evaluationOverlay = $page->evaluate("isOverlayVisible;");
            $isOverlayVisible = $evaluationOverlay->getReturnValue();

            // If the background image is loaded, break out of the loop
            if ($isImageLoaded && $isOverlayVisible) {
                break;
            }

            // Sleep for one second before polling again
            usleep(1000000); // 1000 milliseconds
        }

        // Take a screenshot
        $screenshot = $page->screenshot();
```

Here is one of the HTML I'm dealing

```
<div id="parent-container">
    <div id="overlay" class="primary-overlay-color  h-screen flex items-center justify-center" style="    background: url('./1706812729_65bbe539a65b1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  flex-direction: column;">
        <div class="svg-container"
            style="z-index: 999 !important;padding:.75rem;min-width: 100%;min-height: 356px;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
            <div class="text-white text-center p-3">
                <div class="text-center p-4 text_items_center" style="z-index: 999;padding:1rem;">
                    <h1 class=" sm-font font-extrabold m-px text-color content"  data-textName="text_1">{{text_1}}</h1>
                    <h1 class="content2 sm-font font-extrabold m-4 text-color text-color test2" 
                        data-textName="text_2">{{text_2}}</h1>
     <h1 class="content2 sm-font font-extrabold m-4  text-color test3 " 
                        data-textName="text_3">{{text_3}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you also post minimal HTML code used in the document? And what does overlay dimensions have to do with the dimensions of the background image? Background image cannot control the dimensions of parent.

Comment: Is `$page->setViewport($width, $height)` larger than the image width/height? If not, the image does never fully fit into the window which would raise this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try the code, check **visibility**, **display** and **opacity** properties in **CSS**.

Try this:

```js
// Extended function to check more conditions for visibility
function checkBackgroundImageLoaded() {
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

    // Additional checks for CSS visibility
    const style = getComputedStyle(overlay);
    const isDisplayNone = style.display === 'none';
    const isVisibilityHidden = style.visibility === 'hidden';
    const isOpacityZero = parseFloat(style.opacity) === 0;

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)/i, "$1");

    img.onload = function() {
        const rect = overlay.getBoundingClientRect();
        const isVisible = rect.width > 0 && rect.height > 0 &&
            rect.top >= 0 && rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
            !isDisplayNone && !isVisibilityHidden && !isOpacityZero;

        isBackgroundImageLoaded = true;
        isOverlayVisible = isVisible;
    };

    img.onerror = function() {
        // Handle image load failure
        console.error("Background image failed to load.");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to check if an image is loaded and visible on the page by utilizing the complete property to check if the image has loaded and then checking its visibility using various methods like checking if it's within the viewport or if its dimensions are greater than zero. Here's a sample code demonstrating how you can achieve this:

```js
/ Function to check if an image is loaded and visible
function isImageLoadedAndVisible(img) {
    // Check if the image has been loaded
    if (!img.complete) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if the image is visible on the page
    var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    // Check if the image is within the viewport
    if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.left >= 0 && rect.bottom <= windowHeight && rect.right <= windowWidth) {
        // Check if the image has non-zero dimensions
        if (rect.height > 0 && rect.width > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Usage
var imageElement = document.getElementById('your-image-id');

if (isImageLoadedAndVisible(imageElement)) {
    console.log('Image is loaded and visible.');
} else {
    console.log('Image is not loaded or visible.');
}
```

Replace 'your-image-id' with the actual ID of your image element in the HTML.

This code first checks if the image is loaded using the complete property of the image object. Then it checks if the image is visible on the page by getting its bounding rectangle and comparing it with the dimensions of the viewport. Finally, it also checks if the image has non-zero dimensions to ensure it's not a 1x1 pixel tracking image or something similar.